# Distributing cpp files generated by Cython

Tags: python, c++, gcc, cython

I'm new to Cython and my goal is to use it as some "translator" which compiles basic python code to c++ code which can be distributed and utilized by other users.

I've followed each step in documentation, say I have some file `helloworld.pyx`:

```
print("hello world!")
```

To compile this python code to c++, I create `setup.py` file:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [
    Extension(
        "helloworld",
        sources=["helloworld.pyx"],
        language="c++"
    ),
]

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions),
)
```

Finally I use `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` which produces 2 new files - `helloworld.o`, `helloworld.cpp` and 1 directory - `build`.

Trying to execute script without specifying python directory will give an error `gcc helloworld.cpp`:

> ```
> helloworld.cpp:17:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
> #include "Python.h"
>          ^ 1 error generated.
> ```

When specifying python directory like this `gcc -c -I/usr/include/python2.7 helloworld.cpp -o main.out` it works, but unfortunately the output is encoded in non-readable characters.

---

What would be the proper way to compile python code to cpp code which can be used independently (without specification of python file)?

Thank you!

Comment: Cython-generated cpp code can't be used independently—it compiles into a Python extension module, and extension modules have to be compiled for some Python (so they can then be imported into that same Python). If you build things properly, your `setup.py` will generate an extension module for whichever Python you used to run `setup.py`, which is all you want. You can distribute those binaries (directly, or wrapped up in wheels), or distribute the `.pyx` source and build it on each machine, but anything in between is rarely useful.

Comment: @abarnert Apologies if I misunderstood something but if extension module is generated for python which runs `setup.py` specification will no longer be necessary correct? If so, is there any example for this on documentation? Thanks

Comment: Lots of projects do distribute the intermediate c/c++ files generated by Cython to avoid needing Cython to build so it's definitely doable. (I'm not sure how though)

Comment: `lxml` does this for example ("Building lxml from dev sources" on http://lxml.de/installation.html). Looking at their [setup.py](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/setup.py) might be a good way to work out how

Comment: @ShellRox What do you mean by "specification will no longer be necessary"? Are you referring to the `setup.py`? If so, then yes, it's still necessary, unless you never want to build another copy of the extension again (e.g., after making a bugfix or improvement to the `.pyx` file).

Comment: Another approach is to use a "wheel," which is another kind of Python package (as opposed to many/legacy packages, which are "eggs"). 
 You can include pre-built binary artifacts in a wheel.

Comment: @DavidW You do that by writing a custom `setup.py` that looks for the C++ files and compiles them, and only calls cython if they're missing. But someone who can't even get the basics to work should not be trying to do that.

Comment: @abarnert I agree. One final comment from me (aimed at @ShellRox): Cython modules _cannot_ run without libpython and so it isn't suitable for a standalone C++ program

Comment: So I'm guessing there is no hope for compiling python code to standalone C++ program without getting messy?

Comment: No - it isn't what Cython is designed for.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Conda`, it seems you need the `libpython-dev` package.

Comment: The question was asking how to _remove the dependency_ on Python headers. It was not asking how to install the headers